# Qt networkAccessibleChanged signal not firing

Tags: c++, qt

My configuration :
Windows, QT 5.5.1

I want to monitor the network state (that I simulate by plugging/unpluggin the network cable).

This is my code:

```
mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(mNetManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessibleChanged,
        this, &NetworkTester::updateFlag);
```

The method updateFlag is never called because the signal QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessibleChanged is never fired.

I got around this by setting a timer :

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkNetwork()));
    timer->start(1000);

void NetworkTester::checkNetwork()
{
switch (mNetManager->networkAccessible()) {
case QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible:
    qDebug() << "You are online.";
    break;

case QNetworkAccessManager::NotAccessible:
    qDebug() << "You are offline.";
    break;

case QNetworkAccessManager::UnknownAccessibility:
default:
    qDebug() << "You know nothing, Jon Snow.";
    break;
}
```

}

But I can't seem to detect any change as it always returns QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessible when I plug/unplug network cable.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`QNetworkConfigurationManager` is the class you are looking for. Take a look at `onlineStateChanged(bool isOnline)` signal.

Comment: Thanks for your seggestion.
I tested also using QNetworkConfigurationManager,but the state is always online : 

    QList<QNetworkConfiguration> activeConfigs = mConfManager->allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active);
    qDebug() << "isonline: " << mConfManager->isOnline();

Comment: Do you have only one network interface? Maybe, you have second ethernet cable plugged or connected to wifi network? `isOnline` returns false only if  none of your network connections is active (unplugged/not connected).

Comment: yes: I have 3 network interfaces, one of them is a Virtual Machine interface that I switched off. Even when unplugging all cables I still have an online status

Comment: Are you running your app in virtual machine? If it's the case, then I have a rough guess - in your virtualization software, there may be some (service? hidden?) network interface which gathers your host machine and virtual machine into one (service/hidden/etc) network. It's a very rough guess though. Easiest way to check it - is to run your code outside of virtual machine - on your host machine, for example.

Comment: I switched off my virtual machine (Fedora) and indeed I am working on the host (Windows 7). I discussed the issue with some colleagues and it looks like Qt Api is not stable regarding network access